# mkdir permissions mess up

Tags: php, permissions

I have this simple code

```
mkdir('Users', 0775);
```

but when I go into my directory this is what I see

```
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data 1M Jun 11 16:30 Users
```

I expect to see

```
drwxrwxr-x  4 www-data www-data 1M Jun 11 16:30 Users
```

What could be messing up my permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) might be affecting your script. You can try to temporarily modify it via PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php

```
$old = umask(0);
mkdir('Users', 0775);
umask($old);
```

You could also try to change the permissions *after* the directory is created:

```
mkdir('Users');
chmod('Users', 0775);
```

… which is recommended on multithreaded web servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
mkdir('Users')
chmod('Users', 0775)
```

That could solve your problem, however, keep in mind that mode is ignored on windows, but you can change the permissions with chmod. See [mode is ignored on Windows.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)